# VLC compilation error in Eclipse (in Ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, compilation, vlc

I am trying to export VLC to Eclipse and compile it from there (in Ubuntu).
There have been a number of errors mostly related to the location of some of the header files that I could fix. But now I am getting two errors that I don't know how to fix. The errors are:

**unknown type name ‘pthread_rwlock_t’**
**unknown type name ‘pthread_spinlock_t’**

both of these are used in **"vlc_threads.h"**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you very much,

TJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I removed the c99 compiler option the errors went away, so this error is related to the C99 compiler option in Linux (Ubuntu).